# React Native: Getting error when i try to parse my Datas

Tags: arrays, parsing, object, react-native

Hi I'm trying to parse this Object in an Array:

```
 [ { address: '15 rue de Bouvines',
     category: 'Bar',
     city: 'Tours',
     storeName: 'La Tabtiere',
     _key: '-KuVBzIx8rFZxneg5JvY' },
   { address: '',
     category: '',
     city: '',
     storeName: '',
     _key: '-KuVTSgauvHcvhDigNVz' } ]
```

This is the code where I initialize stuff and where I try to parse the Array:

```
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.tasksRef = firebase.database().ref('/store');
 this.state = {
  user:null,
  loading: true,
  newTask: ""
 }
}

componentDidMount() {
  // start listening for firebase updates
  this.listenForTasks(this.tasksRef);
}

//listener to get data from firebase and update listview accordingly
listenForTasks(tasksRef) {
  tasksRef.on('value', (dataSnapshot) => {
    var tasks = [];
    dataSnapshot.forEach((child) => {
      tasks.push({
        address: child.val().address,
        category: child.val().category,
        city: child.val().city,
        storeName: child.val().storeName,
        _key: child.key
      });
    });

    this.setState({
      tasks:tasks
    });
  });
 }

  this.setState({tasks:tasks}, function(this.state.tasks) {
    ParseArray() {
     return this.state.tasks.map(function(result, i){
      return(
       <View key={i}>
         <Text>{result.address}</Text>
          <View>
            <Text>{result.storeName}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    });
  }
   } 
  );
```

And trying to display using this way:

```
 render() {
  return(
    <View>
      test
      {this.ParseArray()}
    </View>
  )
}
```

But I got this error in xcode:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.tasks.map')

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: Please show code where tasks is set.

Comment: I've updated my code

Comment: I suspect listenForTasks is undefined because it is not bound. You have several options for binding it. Arrow functions in the function declaration, binding the function in the constructor, and binding it in its use case. Just add this in the constructor: `this.listenForTasks = this.listenForTasks.bind(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code is broking somewhere else, but let me state that, setState() is asynchronous.

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

so, updating code as,

```
this.setState({tasks:tasks}, function(this.state.tasks) {
 /** same as ParseValue() **/} 
);
```

will let you to avoid a future (or maybe the current) error.

And when you try to inspect the `this.state.tasks` part, you'll see that, 
`this` is defined and has a value. also `this.state`. But on rendering/mounting phase you can't guarantee that `this.state.tasks` is always defined.

And of course, you can not call `map` on any data structure, other than `Array`.

**UPDATE**

```
this.setState({tasks:tasks}, function(this.state.tasks) {
  return this.state.tasks.map(function(result, i){
    return(
     <View key={i}>
       <Text>{result.address}</Text>
       <View>
         <Text>{result.storeName}</Text>
       </View>
     </View>
  );
 }); 
} 
)
```

I've not followed the opening/closing parathesis/brackets, fix them if necessary.

or, outsorce a function like,

```
ParseArray(array_of_obj) {
 return array_of_obj.map(function(result, i){
  return(
   <View key={i}>
     <Text>{result.address}</Text>
      <View>
        <Text>{result.storeName}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
});
}
```

and use it like,

```
this.setState({tasks: tasks}, function(this.state.tasks) {
  return this.ParseArray(this.state.tasks)
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help but I get another error when I do this, "Unexpected token"

Comment: unexpected token at where?